# Using declaration for type alias template in derived class with tempate base

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

If the base class depends on the template parameter, its scope is not examined in the unqualified name lookup. I can use the `using` declaration to introduce names from the base class. Suppose now I have a type alias template in the base class. Can the `using` declaration be used to introduce it into the derived class?

```
template<class T>
struct Base
{
    using Type1 = int;

    template<typename S>
    using Type2 = S;
};

template<class T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    using typename Base<T>::Type1;           // Fine
    //using Type1 = typename Base<T>::Type1; // Also fine

    template<typename S>
    using Type2 = typename Base<T>::template Type2<S>;
};
```

Can the line for `Type2` be replaced with something similar to the (uncommented) line for `Type1`?

Comment: No, that syntax is not allowed.  Sorry.

Comment: Introducing a template name into the derived class is possible and works fine with `gcc-9.2.0`.

Comment: @cartoonist, is it a compiler extension or a new C++ standard feature? What is the syntax?

Comment: I know about optional `typename` in C++20, but I don't see how it can be used here to introduce `Type2` as a template name.

Comment: Oh, I think I understood your question wrong. The only way that I know (and meant in my comment) is what you have written in the sample code for `Type2` of `Derived` class. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually, the syntax somehow makes sense because it should be denoted that the `Type2` from `Base` class is a template name. It either can be introduced as a template name with template parameter `S` (as you've written) or can be specialised; e.g. `using Type2 = typename Base<T>::template Type2<double>;`

Comment: @cartoonist, what I meant is something simple like this: `using Base<T>::Type2;`, possibly with `typename`s and `template`s.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template<class T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    using Base<T>::Type2;

    void foo() {
        // Using the Type2 alias template
        // inside our class to declare a local variable.
        typename Derived::template Type2<int> i;
    }
};

// Using the Type2 alias template
// outside the class to declare another type.
using X = Derived<int>::Type2<int>;
```

This is the correct syntax, and all compilers that support C++11 should allow this. [See here for a live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ajvG46Mzd).

> what I meant is something simple like this: `using Base<T>::Type2;`, possibly with `typename`s and `template`s.

We don't need these disambiguators in the `using` declaration, but when we want to use `Type2` in `Derived`, we still need:

- the `template` disambiguator because `Type2` is a template and `Derived` is dependent on `T`
- the `typename` disambiguator to specify that `Type2<...>` is a type

---

*See also: [cppreference article on dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)*

Comment: [It doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/G67595bnj) like `Type2` in my example.

Comment: @Evg you still need `typename` and `template` when using this alias in `Derived`. I've adjusted the answer to cover this.

Comment: That was the point of the question - avoid `typename` and `template`. But in this case you don't need `using Base<T>::Type2;` at all because `Type2` will be inherited from `Base`. Also try adding `Derived<int> d; d.foo();` to force a compiler to instantiate `foo()`.

Comment: @Evg you're asking the impossible then. There is no way to create a using-declaration that disambiguates whether the member we're introducing into our scope is a template or not. There is only the `using typename Base<T>::Type1;` syntax to disambiguate for types. See https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declarator

Answer (score 0):

The prolem such syntax solves is that potentially type `Base<T>` used as base type can be specialized after this definition but before instantiation of `Derived`.

Most of the time such syntax work as long as `Type2` is template. Possible XY problem here is that you try to get more a general syntax. Sadly, it's impossible. Solution would be only to separate type definitions from `Derived` class.