# Reusing template variable from base class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Let's consider such class hierarchy

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    template<typename...U>
    constexpr static bool SOME_TRAIT = std::is_constructible_v<T,U...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    //some usage of SOME_TRAIT
};
```

To use it in `Dervied` I have to use sth like:

```
template<typename...U>
constexpr static bool SOME_TRAIT = Base<T>::template SOME_TRAIT<U...>;
```

Which can be noisy. Is there something like `using` declaration for member functions, but usable for `SOME_TRAIT`?

Comment: Unfortunately, [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445594/using-declaration-for-type-alias-template-in-derived-class-with-tempate-base).

Comment: @Evg: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but what about declaring `template<typename...U> using BASE_TRAIT = typename Base<T>::template SOME_TRAIT<U...>;` in `Derived`? Doesn't that work? What did I get wrong?

Comment: @andreee, the idea is not to repeat it at all, but simply say `using Base<T>::SOME_TRAIT;`. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The Notes section on [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) also explicitly states that this is all not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Or, rather, you've already found the best way to do it.

The problem is, the parser needs to have the shape of `SOME_TRAIT` explained to it. `using SOME_TRAIT` wouldn't give it any more information about whether the `<` and `>` in `SOME_TRAIT<foo>` should be interpreted as operators or delimiters. The language standard requires that that be done at the point of definition of `Derived`, rather than waiting until `Derived` is actually specialized and used, and so it can't assume that `SOME_TRAIT` will always be a variable template (because `Base` might be given a specialization later on). What you're giving it there, other than the `bool` and naming `U`, is the minimum amount of information the parser needs to do its job.

Comment: Could something like `using Base<T>::template SOME_TRAIT;` work in theory?

Comment: @Evg I'm not sure. I don't see any obvious reason why one couldn't stuff it into the language, given that it mirrors the use of the identifier, but the fact that `using typename` is explicitly supported and this isn't suggests that there might be some subtle ambiguity. At the very least, it would be a weird complication that you could declare a templated variable without its arity being known.

Comment: @evg See the Notes section on [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). The variant with template is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @n314159, my question was whether there is some fundamental reason why it is forbidden.

Comment: @Evg I suspect the most fundamental reason is that it's just going too far. In something like `foo.template bar<4, int, std::vector>()`, the arity and, uh, meta-type (?) of the parameters can be trivially inferred from the arguments. Having `using` introduce an alias for which that information is unavailable strains the concept of an alias quite a bit.